# input from form being converted to decimal on insert

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a db column for upc codes setup as a 'numeric' data type in postgres.

I generated scaffolding to input values into this table, but rails is converting the input in FLOAT for some reason,

eg, a 13 digit number entry  1234567890000 is converted to 1234567890000.0

from the logs:

INSERT INTO "upc_codes" ("upccode") VALUES (1234567890000.0) RETURNING "id"

Where is the data type for the SQL statement being set, or not set as the case may be?

Comment: When you set the column type to NUMERIC are you specifying the precision/scale like this: `NUMERIC(13,0)`? (13 is precision, 0 is scale)

Answer (score 0):

What data type are using for this column? Try changing the column type to an integer in a migration:

```
change_column :upc_codes, :upc_code, :integer
```

Comment: create_table :upc_codes do |t|
      t.integer :upccode

      t.timestamps
    end

Comment: I discovered that if I change the data type to INTEGER instead of NUMERIC via pgadmin, the views start showing the number without decimals (as they are stored). The problem is I don't want to use the INTEGER data type

Answer (score 0):

max integer value for an mysql integer should be 2147483647 .
i will suppose this could cause an errors somewhere .

try to change the coulm into a **bigint** .

aniway ,from my experience is better to handle bignum using string in rails (in this manner you could saftly change db). you could always use to_i later in your code .

sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the column type to `NUMERIC` are you specifying the precision/scale like this: `NUMERIC(13,0)`? (13 is precision, 0 is scale)

I submitted this again as an answer because I guess I commented when I should have answered.